# Java generics: Is this safe enough?

Tags: java, generics

Consider the following code snippets:

```
public interface FieldEnum {
    public String getEnumName();
}
```

---

```
public enum InvoiceStatus implements FieldEnum {
    UNCHECKED("unchecked"),
    ERROR("error"),
    OK("ok");

    private final String enumName;

    private InvoiceStatus(final String enumName) {
        this.enumName = enumName;
    }

    @Override
    public String getEnumName() {
        return enumName;
    }
}
```

---

```
private InvoiceBean(final Integer invoiceId, final Integer businessPartnerId, final String invoiceNumber, final Date invoiceDate, final BigDecimal priceExclVAT, final BigDecimal VAT, final BigDecimal priceInclVAT, final BigDecimal paymentDiscount, final InvoiceStatus status) {
    this.invoiceId = invoiceId;
    this.businessPartnerId = businessPartnerId;
    this.invoiceNumber = invoiceNumber;
    this.invoiceDate = invoiceDate;
    this.priceExclVAT = priceExclVAT;
    this.VAT = VAT;
    this.priceInclVAT = priceInclVAT;
    this.paymentDiscount = paymentDiscount;
    this.status = status;
}

public InvoiceBean(final ResultSet rs) throws SQLException {
    this(rs.getInt(1), rs.getInt(2), rs.getString(3), rs.getDate(4), rs.getBigDecimal(5), rs.getBigDecimal(6), rs.getBigDecimal(7), rs.getBigDecimal(8), EnumConverter.convert(rs.getString(9), InvoiceStatus.values()));
}
```

Is the following code safe?

```
public class EnumConverter {
    public static <T extends FieldEnum> T convert(String enumName, T[] enumValues) {
        for (T enumValue : enumValues) {
            if (enumName.equals(enumValue.getEnumName())) {
                return enumValue;
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalStateException("orm.enums.EnumConverter.convert: No suitable enum has been found. enumName = " + enumName + " fieldEnums = " + enumValues);
    }
}
```

or would there be any advantages by using this? (Note the addition of `Class<T> clazz` argument)

```
public class EnumConverter {
    public static <T extends FieldEnum> T convert(String enumName, T[] enumValues, Class<T> clazz) {
        for (T enumValue : enumValues) {
            if (enumName.equals(enumValue.getEnumName())) {
                return enumValue;
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalStateException("orm.enums.EnumConverter.convert: No suitable enum has been found. enumName = " + enumName + " fieldEnums = " + enumValues);
    }
}
```

And then call it via `EnumConverter.convert(rs.getString(9), InvoiceStatus.values(), InvoiceStatus.class)` of course.

Regards.

Comment: Safe enough for what?

Comment: Since you're not using the `clazz` parameter, I don't see how the second solution could be any better.

Comment: What's wrong with InvoiceStatus.valueOf(myString)?

Comment: If you want others to check your code probably  http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ would be better place.

Comment: @Keppil "Safe" is well-defined in Generics, it is not something opinion-based. Don't have a link unfortunately though.

Comment: @skiwi: `Safe` I can understand. `Safe enough` implies there is some kind of half-way that I am unaware of, hence my question.

Comment: @Keppil Ah got it, my bad, I just meant "safe".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generics use the class type of the first `T` type argument.  Adding the new `Class<T>` does not add any more safeness.  In fact, you are now requiring that you have know what class to put in the list of arguments, which can be cumbersome.

Answer (score 8):

A straightforward answer is to forget the EnumConverter and instead use `InvoiceStatus.valueOf(rs.getString(9));`

Comment: This does not take care of the fact that I want to compare it with the `.getEnumName()`, now it just takes the normal `.name()` from an Enum, and that is not 100% the behaviour I am searching for, I could however look into the possibility to override `name()`.

Answer (score 0):

The extra parameter is not needed - the compiler will be able to determine the type T from the passed array, so there is no need to explicitly take the Class as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use something like:

```
public enum InvoiceStatus implements FieldEnum {
    UNCHECKED("unchecked"),
    ERROR("error"),
    OK("ok");

    private static final Map<String, InvoiceStatus> invoiceStatusMap = new HashMap<>(values().length);

    static{
        for (InvoiceStatus  invoiceStatus : values()) {
            invoiceStatusMap.put(invoiceStatus.enumName, invoiceStatus);
        }
    }    
    private final String enumName;

    private InvoiceStatus(final String enumName) {
        this.enumName = enumName;
    }

    @Override
    public String getEnumName() {
        return enumName;
    }

    public static InvoiceStatus getInvoiceStatus(String enumName){
        if (invoiceStatusMap.contains(enumName)){
           return invoiceStatusMap.get(enumName);
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("No suitable enum has been found. enumName = " + enumName + " fieldEnums = " + enumValues);
        }
    }
}
```